# In my out put, from where did come "false"?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, while-loop

Here is my Input:

```
var slaying = true;
var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random()*5 + 1);
var totalDamage = 0;

while (slaying){
if(youHit){
    console.log("You hit!");
    }
else{
    console.log("You missed!");
    }
slaying = false;

}
```

My Out Put:

```
You hit!
false
```

I need to know from where did come this " false" word in my out put? I know my 1st line of my output. I'm also clear about youHit and damageThisRound function. I just to know how it's working in execution time.

Comment: I ran your code in JSFiddle and did not get the second line in the console, just the first.

Comment: but my codecademy compiler shown that line.

Comment: it's probably something extra that codeacademy is adding - I wouldn't worry about it ,   that  won't get logged in real application , at least not from that code

Answer (score 0):

when you run the script in the console the while inclusion will show you the boolean as a result like when you put

```
var foo = 'bar';
```

you will have undefined as a result.

But in your webpage you won't have the result.